# Call URL in Background (Hidden) C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an anonymous php emailer (confirmed working) that accepts query strings, and I would like to call it in an MVC C# web application with something like:

http://www.example.com/mailGateway.php?password=myPassword&to=me@example.com&from=webmaster@example.com&subject=asdf&message=hi,%20how%20are%20you?";

If it were WinForms, I would (I imagine) make a WebBrowser and change the control visibility. The process has to be completely hidden from the client, and preferably server-side. I do not have access to the passwords, just the requirement to use the anonymous mailer. What is the most efficient way to accomplish this in C#?

Comment: Please tell me that password parameter is not for real :)

Comment: lol, that password parameter is not for real. Just showing an example of a query string

Comment: Oh good. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/268/how-to-send-email-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a WebBrowser to do this. Just use System.Net.WebRequest

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUriString);
WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Alternatively, System.Net.WebClient is also an option if you want something more abstracted/higher level.